# table max-height 100% of div position fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a div:

```
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

and inside this div is a table:

```
height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

and when table cells gets some data, table grows down, but always not bigger than div container. This work well but not in Firefox 13, table grows down to bigger than fixed positioned container.

How can I fix it?

Comment: try removing Max-height:100% because having both does not make much sence

Comment: both cases dont work, with or without ive tried.

Comment: Percentual values of the `height` selector does not work by default. The parent div must have a height value assigned first.

Comment: What if parent height depends on window height as in example above.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your "div css" and it will fix all your problems: `overflow: auto;`

`overflow: auto;` will add vertical or horizontal scrollbars as needed while `overflow: scroll;` will add both regardless and disable (but still remain visible) the one that's not in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A table's dimensions are rigid. The content of the cells can never break through it. This means that it will, whether you like it or not, grow in width and/or height, and will ignore your CSS rules if needed.

The solution? Use `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` on the container `div`, so it adds scrollbars as necessary.